# Use the include tag with an already present GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I created a action bar in xml for use in all activities. I used the `include` tag for it.
One of my activities have just a `GridView` tag. you can see it's source below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gv_level"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

It doesn't have any problem but when I add the `include` tag or any other tag to this (similar below source)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    layout="@layout/action_bar" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gv_level"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

It doesn't give me an error but the `GridView` is hidden when the activity appears.
Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the gridview is hidden when activity apear. it there ant solution
>   for it? thanks.

You may want to either set the *orientation* of the `LinearLayout` to *vertical* so your included layout doesn't push the `GridView` outside of the screen on the right or you could use `wrap_content` for the included layout's width. Using the orientation change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    layout="@layout/action_bar" />
// ... rest of the layout
```

Comment: oops. I thought default orientation is vertical. thanks. it works great.